# How to access a button from another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have a firstViewController and a secondViewController. The first one contains a firstButton and the second one - a secondButton. Here's what I want to do: when user clicks the secondButton, some firstButton's property changes.

Unfortunately, when I create an instance of a firstViewController in a secondViewController and then trying to access a firstButton, I get an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

So, technically, I'm trying to do this as follows:

```
var ins = firstViewController() 

@IBAction func secondButtonisPressed(){
    ins.firstButton.alpha = 0
}
```

What is the proper way to implement that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two view controllers? Does the `firstViewController` present the `secondViewController`? Is your goal to update the button of the existing `firstViewController` from the `secondViewController`?

Comment: My bad, rmaddy. The reply was intended for user2387685.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the `IBOutlets` of your `firstViewController` are only available (`!= nil`) after the `viewDidLoad()` `firstViewController`'s method has being called.

In other words, you have to **present the view**, before you can make any changes to a `UIViewController IBOutlet`.

> How you can solve this?

Add a variable into `FirstViewController` that works as a flag for you.

for example: `var hideFirstButton = false`

in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method of `FirstViewController` check for `hideFirstButton`'s value and **hide** or **show** your `firstButton`.

Then, before you present your `FirstViewController` change the value of `hideFirstButton` to the needed for your application to run fine.

> **UPDATE**:

Other workaround, using **Storyboard** is (**This approach has the inconvenient that the completion handler is called after `viewWillAppear`() so the button is visible for a second**):

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    self.presentViewController(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        //This lines will be called after the view is loaded so the code will run
        firstViewController.firstButton.alpha = 0
    })
```

> **EXAMPLE:** [an example at GitHub](https://github.com/halonsoluis/ViewControllerHideButtonExample)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Hugo :) 

I get the idea and the reasons why I didn't succeed with my implementation, but unfortunately, I have some blind spots in your realization. 

Wouldn't it be too hard for you to sent me the project, that uses this particular approach? That would really help.

Comment: There's no problem, give me a few minutes, to publish it on github

Comment: Looking forward to it.

Comment: You can check for it now

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do this using delegation, similar to the way Apple does it in their existing frameworks. For an example, look at the way that you use UITableViewDelegate when working with a UITableView object.

If you wanted to use delegation to tell `secondViewController` that `firstButton` was pressed using delegation, you could do it as follows:

**Step 1:**
Create a protocol containing a method for the button press event.

```
protocol buttonPressDelegate {
    func buttonPressed() -> Void
}
```

**Step 2:** 
In `firstViewController`, declare that you have an instance of an object of type `buttonPressProtocol`.

```
var buttonPressDelegateObj: buttonPressDelegate?
```

**Step 3:**

In `firstViewController`, initialize your `buttonPressDelegateObj` to contain a reference to your instance of secondViewController. If you want you can create a method to set the reference contained in `buttonPressDelegateObj`, or do it `viewDidLoad` in `firstViewController`, etc.

```
buttonPressDelegateObj = secondViewControllerObj
```

**Step 4:**

In `secondViewController`, declare that you adopt the `buttonPressDelegate` protocol.

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController, buttonPressDelegate {
```

**Step 5:**

In `secondViewController`, implement the protocol method `buttonPressed()` by adding the function with your desired implementation. Here's an example:

```
func buttonPressed() {
   secondButton.alpha = 0
}
```

**Step 6:**

Create an @IBAction on the button in `firstViewController`, so that when the button is pressed it calls `buttonPressDelegateObj.buttonPressed()` and you can respond to the event

```
@IBAction func firstButtonPressed() {
   if (buttonPressDelegateObj != nil) {
      buttonPressDelegateObj.buttonPressed()
   }
   else {
      print("You forgot to set your reference in buttonPressDelegateObj to contain an instance of secondViewController!")
   }
}
```

Note: This is just one way that you could do this. To tell `firstViewController` that `secondButton` was pressed (go the other way), have `firstViewController` implement the protocol `buttonPressDelegate`, have `secondViewController` contain a reference to `firstViewController` as an instance of type `buttonPressDelegate?`, and create an `@IBAction` in `secondViewController` that fires when `secondButton` is pressed that calls your the `buttonPressDelegate` method.

Note: There is a similar pattern employed in the Android world to get a `Fragment` to communicate to an `Activity`, that you can read more about [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Seems good to me. I'll give it a try any time soon, just one question. Where should I put buttonPressDelegate protocol (step 1)? In secondViewController?

Comment: @IvanPanshin: As long as it is in your project it should be fine. What I typically do is make different folders in my Xcode project for the different parts of my application. So for example, my current project has a folder called Delegates, and in there I just made a swift file called ScreenDelegateProtocol.swift.